# Distributed memcached but 'get' from localhost only

Tags: php, memcached

I have n web servers running Apache / PHP and one database server. I want to use memcached, and my current strategy is to have each web server do double duty as a node in the memcached pool, so that there is a 1 / n chance the 'get' from memcached will be from localhost and thus much faster than traversing the network to another web server.

Ideally, I would like to always 'get' from localhost, and 'set' to all, so that the cache will never be stale on any machine, and I will always get the performance benefit from reading from the localhost memory. I realize this is counter to the distributed philosophy of memcached, but the nature of the way that data is read / written in my application would make this kind of setup hugely beneficial in terms of performance.

Is this possible with memcached, or should I be looking at another solution?

Comment: You realise that memcache doesn't work like this: it doesn't replicate in a cluster... a value will only ever be stored on one node in that cluster, not all of them, so "'set' to all" simply isn't an option

Comment: If you need "'set' to all" use redis, not memcache.... a redis cluster does support replication across all nodes in the cluster... meaning you can read/write to any node in the cluster, and the data will be shared across all the nodes